# Error inflating class <unknown> Android

Tags: android, xml

Добрый день. Подскажите, какие причины могут вызывать Error inflating class ? Например 2 разметки. В первой все отрабатывает, при загрузки торой приложение падает.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.widget.lavkaviews.text.Text
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3 товара на сумму"
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
    <com.widget.lavkaviews.text.Text
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/summ"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ruble"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/description" />
    <com.widget.lavkaviews.PriceText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/finish"
        android:text="ОФОРМИТЬ"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/main"
        android:background="@color/lavka_main_red" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Вторая

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--android:background="@color/main"-->


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/image" />
    <com.widget.lavkaviews.text.Text
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image" />

    <com.widget.lavkaviews.PriceText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/price"/>

    <!--<com.widget.lavkaviews.PriceText-->
        <!--android:layout_width="80dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="20dp"-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/price"-->
        <!--android:textColor="#262626"-->
        <!--android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />-->

    <com.widget.lavkaviews.Dropdown
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/portion"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/incrementor" />
    <!--android:layout_below="@+id/price"-->

    <com.widget.lavkaviews.Incrementor
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/incrementor"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/portion" />
    <com.widget.core.view.ProductNDIndicator
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nd"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Класс, который не распознаётся - PriceText.Ошибка появляется и на физическом устройстве и на эмуляторе, в одном и том же месте, на второй разметке. Судяпо стектрейсу - в месте объявления. Отличий на мой взгляд нет.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                           at com.lavkalavka.pages.cart.CartFragment$CartAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(CartFragment.java:241)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5223)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4449)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4359)
                                                                           at com.widget.core.layoutmanagers.LinearLayoutManager.measureChild(LinearLayoutManager.java:235)
                                                                           at com.widget.core.layoutmanagers.LinearLayoutManager.onMeasure(LinearLayoutManager.java:125)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2563)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                           at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1196)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                           at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:318)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                           at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1196)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                           at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:318)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:940)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
                                                                        at android.view.View.
```

Comment: Хм...А если это убрать совсем: `com.widget.core.view.ProductNDIndicator`?

Comment: стактрейс ошибки дайте

Comment: Юрий, а чем Вам оно не нравится?) С ним всё прекрасно работало, до того, как я сделал PriceText. Попробую, но сильно сомневаюсь, что в этом дело

Comment: Юрий, не помогло

Comment: тыкну пальцем в небо
com.widget.lavkaviews.PriceText попробуйте поменять на com.widget.lavkaviews.text.PriceText

Comment: Да, все таки  я не очень корректно задал вопрос. PriceText это RelativeLayout с Text и ImageView, выровненных по центру по ввертикали для достижения корректности и гладкости отображения. ImageView используется для представление сивола рубля. com.widget.lavkaviews в данном случае это package, где PriceText лежит, так что путь совершенно точно указан верно.